# Hide a property from Swagger UI without json ignore

Tags: c#, swagger-ui

I have a property that I want to hide from the Swagger UI but it needs to be used internally for serializing so I'm unable to use JsonIgnore in this situation. Is there an alternative that can be used to hide the property but only on the Swagger UI?

Comment: You could hack the document.xml and remove it, it's not an automatic solution though :/

Comment: Hide from the Model structure or from the auto-generated JSON examples?

Comment: Your Swagger UI Examples should be seperate from your models. Create a seperate class under an Examples folder.